# Is there a good javascript snippet anyone knows for formatting "abbreviated" numbers?

Tags: javascript, string-formatting, number-formatting

The key is **abbreviated**. For example, `1m` instead of `1000000`, and `12k` instead of `12000` etc. - much like on StackOverflow!

I'm not sure what else to add other than I've tried:

`format numbers abbreviated javascript`
`format numbers short javascript`

And a few other searches and scoured the results with no luck. I feel like *someone* must have done this before, hate reinventing wheels and all that!

Cheers

**Edit: I'm looking to take a number, i.e. `12345` and turn it into `12k`**

Sorry I wasn't very clear!

Comment: 12k may also be 12288 - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilobyte

Comment: You could have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177855/how-to-format-numbers-similar-to-stack-overflow-reputation-format) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134161/format-number-like-stackoverflow-rounded-to-thousands-with-k-suffix) and reverse it... :)

Comment: Do you want `1000 -> 1k` or `1k -> 1000` ?

Answer (score 4):

Here's some code I've written quite some time ago but it works fine. It even supports decimals.

```
function is_numeric(string) {
    for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        if(string.charAt(i) < '0' || string.charAt(i) > '9') {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function charValueMultiplier(letter) {
    switch(letter) {
        case 'M':
        case 'm': return 1000000;
        case 'k':
        case 'K': return 1000;
        default: return 0;
    }
}

// parse string like 1.5M or 10k and return the number
function parseNumber(string) {
    string = string.replace(/ /g, ''); // remove spaces
    var total           = 0;
    var partial         = 0;
    var partialFraction = 0;
    var fractionLength  = 0;
    var isFraction      = false;

    // process the string; update total if we find a unit character
    for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        var c = string.substr(i, 1);
        if(c == '.' || c == ',') {
            isFraction = true;
        }
        else if(is_numeric(c)) {
            if(isFraction) {
                partialFraction = partialFraction * 10 + parseInt(c, 10);
                fractionLength++;
            }
            else {
                partial = partial * 10 + parseInt(c, 10);
            }
        }
        else {
            total += charValueMultiplier(c) * partial + charValueMultiplier(c) * partialFraction / Math.pow(10, fractionLength);

            partial         = 0;
            partialFraction = 0;
            fractionLength  = 0;
            isFraction      = false;
        }
    }

    return Math.round(total + partial + partialFraction / Math.pow(10, fractionLength));
}
```

Comment: I think you should add a `g` to  `string.replace(/ /, '')` but other than that, I believe you ;) +1

Comment: hi new to js @ThiefMaster - is this easily able to be convert large (bigint) numbers like Trillion 10^12 (T) Quadrillion 10^15 (P) and Quintillion 10^18 (E) - if so can you walk me through it please if you have time

Answer (score 1):

I made an npm package that can do this for you: https://www.npmjs.com/package/approximate-number

Usage for Node.js (or browsers via Browserify):

```
npm install --save approximate-number
```

and then in your code:

```
var approx = require('approximate-number');
approx(123456); // "123k"
```

Or, for usage in browsers via Bower:

```
bower install approximate-number
```

And then

```
window.approximateNumber(123456); // "123k"
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you *have* a number `n` and want to format it to a string. Then

```
// n being the number to be formatted
var s = "" + n; // cast as string
if (n >= 1000000) {
  s = s.substring(0, s.length - 6) + "M";
} else if (n >= 1000) {
  s = s.substring(0, s.length - 3) + "k";
}
```

should do the job. You can of course extend it to your needs or even include numbers `< 1`.

Comment: I think it should be the other way round... but I'm not sure.