# highchart with numberformat (unit)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) to generate a line chart.

And I'm having a problem with `numberFormat`:

```
var test = 15975000;
numberFormat(test, 0,',','.');
```

the result is: `15.975.000`

But I want to transform `1000` to `1k`, `100000` to `100k`, `1000000` to `1m` like this.
How can I deal with this problem?

Answer (score 9):

numberFormat is available in Highcharts object.

```
Highcharts.numberFormat(test, 0,',','.');
```

Example http://jsfiddle.net/DaBYc/1/

```
yAxis: {
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value,0);
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: "But I want to transform 1000 to 1k, 100000 to 100k, 1000000 to 1m like this. How can I deal with this problem?" I can't see that this solves that?

Answer (score 6):

Write your own [formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.formatter) (see this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/labels-formatter-linked/)).

```
formatter: function() {
  result = this.value;
  if (this.value > 1000000) { result = Math.floor(this.value / 1000000) + "M" }
  else if (this.value > 1000) { result = Math.floor(this.value / 1000) + "k" }
  return result;
}
```

See also: [How to format numbers similar to Stack Overflow reputation format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177855/how-to-format-numbers-similar-to-stack-overflow-reputation-format)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to do that:

```
                labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                     return abbrNum(this.value,2); // Need to call the function for each value shown by the chart
                }
            },
```

---

Here is the Function used to transform the data to be inserted on javascript:

```
    function abbrNum(number, decPlaces) {
    // 2 decimal places => 100, 3 => 1000, etc
    decPlaces = Math.pow(10,decPlaces);

    // Enumerate number abbreviations
    var abbrev = [ "k", "m", "b", "t" ];

    // Go through the array backwards, so we do the largest first
    for (var i=abbrev.length-1; i>=0; i--) {

        // Convert array index to "1000", "1000000", etc
        var size = Math.pow(10,(i+1)*3);

        // If the number is bigger or equal do the abbreviation
        if(size <= number) {
             // Here, we multiply by decPlaces, round, and then divide by decPlaces.
             // This gives us nice rounding to a particular decimal place.
             number = Math.round(number*decPlaces/size)/decPlaces;

             // Handle special case where we round up to the next abbreviation
             if((number == 1000) && (i < abbrev.length - 1)) {
                 number = 1;
                 i++;
             }

             // Add the letter for the abbreviation
             number += abbrev[i];

             // We are done... stop
             break;
        }
    }

    return number;
}
```

Hope this works =)

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to format a Highstock chart:

```
   tooltip: {
        pointFormatter: function() {
          var result = this.y;
        let header = '<table>';
        let body = '<tr><td style = "color: ' + this.series.color + ';padding:0">'
          + this.series.name + ': </td><td style = "padding:0"><b>';
        if (result > 1000000) {
          result = Math.floor(result / 1000000) + "M"
        }
        else if (result > 1000) {
          result = Math.floor(result / 1000) + "k"
        }
        return header + body + result + '</b></td></tr></table>';
        }
    },
```

I had trouble finding a way of adding Millions and Thousands while not hampering the data grouping functionality or the date.