# Highstock (Highcharts): Show tooltip values in million/billion etc. automatically

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Very similar to the question stated in the problem blow, I want to automatically show big numbers using k, M etc. (1200 => 1.2k).

[highcharts tooltip format millions billions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16260364/highcharts-tooltip-format-millions-billions)

This seems to work for standard **Highcharts** plots but not for **Highstock** plots. My guess is that this is due to Highstock not having yAxis?

See, e.g., http://jsfiddle.net/1zhga6bm/1/

Would anyone know how to adjust the code below so that it works in Highstock?

```
var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'USD to EUR',
        data: [10000, 1000000]
    }],

    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '',
        formatter: function () {
          var ret = '',
          multi,
          axis = this.series.yAxis,
          numericSymbols = ['k', 'M', 'G', 'T', 'P', 'E'],
          i = numericSymbols.length;

          while (i-- && ret === '') {
                    multi = Math.pow(1000, i + 1);
                    if (axis.tickInterval >= multi && numericSymbols[i] !== null) {
                        ret = Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y / multi, -1) + numericSymbols[i];
                    }
                }
                return ret;
            }
        }

});
```

Adjusted JSfiddle from below comment.

Many thanks!

Comment: Your example is missing some points : Your data does not have values like "1200" or "10000" or greater AND you are not using the tooltip formatter described in your question.
Please update those 2 points first

Comment: Hi @S-UP, That functionality works in the same way in Highstock:http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/84omuaep/

Comment: Thanks for extending on my example. I have added your code but it does not seem to run. Note, I have no JS background. I use R and highcharter as a wrapper. But I have successfully included pure JS code for the tooltip in the past.